# Convert email in image type to text with Python

Tags: scrapy

I've stumbled upon a website that in order to protect its content converts normal text to an image so it cannot be easily scraped with spiders.

**This is the code:**

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMainCol_CompanyDetailsInfoData1_imgMail"
 src="https://www.bizi.si/ImageGenerator.aspx?JXwFUy4U5m5jKwuO3IgV3ASgH0Id5ve7uMFqS922Ezc6IUi0sEN3kHSxb0hVFQZUGP73%2bADQ6cwFmaVlY5EkzN0wTftd%2bET2KzDb1TxL434%3d">
```

The URL that contains business email looks like:

https://www.bizi.si/ImageGenerator.aspx?JXwFUy4U5m5jKwuO3IgV3ASgH0Id5ve7uMFqS922Ezc6IUi0sEN3kHSxb0hVFQZUGP73%2bADQ6cwFmaVlY5EkzN0wTftd%2bET2KzDb1TxL434%3d

Which when rendered displays as the following image:

[image]

Does anyone has any idead how could the above url be decoded in normal text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must download the image (yield a `Request` for the image URL, the image bytes will be available at `response.body`) and use an OCR solution such as https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract.